# Type-N vs SMA connector (relative merits)

Tags: rf, connector

What are the relative merits of using a [Type-N connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_connector) vs an [SMA connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMA_connector) for an RF application up to \$18\,\text{GHz}\$? From the type-N wikipedia page (linked), it's stated that the type-N connector is favored when ruggedness is required. What does this mean specifically? In comparison with an SMA connector, does this mean that the type-N connector has a higher rated number of mating cycles? Some of my additional guesses are that it's more difficult to bend the inner conductor pin of a type-N and that the dielectric between the inner and outer conductors is less exposed to scratching during mating than the SMA connector. An additional advantage of type-N connectors is that they are meant to be hand-tightened, whereas SMA connectors should be tightened with a torque wrench to achieve the best performance.

The main advantage of the SMA connector seems to be size, since it's quite a bit smaller. This means that it's easier and cheaper to mount to a PCB (requires less board space) and (as far as I can tell) there are a lot more options for SMA PCB connectors than for type-N. Is there an additional performance benefit to SMA connectors? Some manufacturers offer SMA connectors good up to \$26.5\,\text{GHz}\$, whereas I haven't seen the same for type-N connectors. Additionally, the higher performance connectors (3.5mm, 2.92mm, etc.) look a bit like SMA connectors (and indeed some can be mated with SMA). Does this mean that it's easier to achieve better performance (e.g., lower [VSWR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave_ratio)) with the structure of an SMA connector?

Are there any other advantages/disadvantages to each that I haven't mentioned? Are my guesses correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already worked out for yourself some of the important differences.

One that you missed is power handling. The N-type connector can typically handle about 3x the signal power of the SMA without overheating:

[image]

(Image source: [Southwest Microwave](https://mpd.southwestmicrowave.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Southwest-Microwave-Power-Rating.pdf))

The peak power capability (governed by the dielectric breakdown limit) is similarly higher for N-type compared to SMA, due to the greater distance between inner and outer conductors. For example, Amphenol rates their SMA connectors for 1000 V rms ([source](https://www.amphenolrf.com/connectors/sma-connectors.html)) and their N-type connectors for 1500 V ([source](https://www.amphenolrf.com/connectors/n-type-connectors.html)).

Answer (score 0):

> From the type-N wikipedia page (linked), it's stated that the type-N connector is favored when ruggedness is required. What does this mean specifically?

Type N is about 10 times larger than SMA this means it's harder to break.

> does this mean that the type-N connector has a higher rated number of mating cycles?

That would be "durability" not "ruggedness"

Comment: So, durability means resistance to wear (i.e., continual use) and ruggedness means resistance to one-off breaks?

Comment: @MattHusz I would actually call number of cycles endurance rather than durability, but whatever it is, it is certainly not ruggednness. That said, I think the article actually does mean ruggedness (ability to survive harsh environments and handling) and not number of cycles. Durable is rather catch-all and can mean whatever you want it to mean.